# ELastic APM error while running with docker

Tags: java, docker, elasticsearch, elastic-apm

I have running the application in java microservices - docker. For monitoring purpose ahve installed elastic APM.
below is my dockerfile Entrypoint:

```
ENTRYPOINT [
    "java",
    "-javaagent:/opt/build/workspace/auth-service-apm/elastic-apm-agent-1.38.0.jar",
    "-Delastic.apm.service_name=auth-service",
    "-Delastic.apm.server_urls=http://APM-Public-IP:8200",
    "-Delastic.apm.secret_token=",
    "-Delastic.apm.environment=dev",
    "-Delastic.apm.application_packages=com.tcg",
    "-jar",
    "-Dspring.profiles.active=dev",
    "-DMONGO_DB_URL=mongodb://username:password@xxx.xx.xx.xxx:27017/tcg",
    "-DEUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULT_ZONE=http://yy.yy.yy.yy:8761/eureka/",
    "/app.jar"
]
```

but when running docker run image-id getting below error:

> Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /opt/build/workspace/auth-service-apm/elastic-apm-agent-1.38.0.jar
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
> agent library failed to init: instrument

have checked the apm jar file path and permission its is correct. Please guide further

the metrics should be logged into APM server

Comment: Hi, this question lacks details could you provide the whole docker file or docker compose

Comment: It worked after added elastic jar to docker file

Comment: Great, you should post an answer then for other ;)